# How to mount another hard drive as /Users on OS X?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, mount, hfs+

I replaced a 320 GB HDD with a 128 GB SSD on my Apple laptop, but it turns out that I don't have enough space to put my own stuff under /Users.

I know in Linux systems people can mount another HDD as /home or /usr, so I want to know whether it's possible for HFS+.

Comment: You really want to always carry an external hard drive around? Just symlink some folders in your user home..?

Comment: You can also change the library location of iTunes by pressing *Option* while starting iTunes.

Comment: ...and no, I don't want to always carry an external hard drive, I use an 2.5" hdd replaced the optical drive, which rarely be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Accounts Preference Pane, right click (control click seems to work better for some reason) on the user whose home folder you want to move and select Advanced Options… From there you can choose a new location for the home folder that will take effect upon reboot.

Comment: Hi penguirl, I tried to right click (and control click) on the user account name on the list in the Accounts pref pane, but nothing did happen. I'm using Snow Leopard 10.6.6, is that a feature by a third party software? or deprecated in this version? Thanks!

Comment: I found it was my mistake that I forgot to unlock the section, anyway, it works now! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just as under Linux, use [`/etc/fstab`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/fstab.5.html) to specify volumes to make mountable.

Comment: I'm trying this on ElCapitan, but it doesn't seem to be working, not even with `/-     -fstab` in `auto_master`. At the first reboot it hangs after login.